# No write permission in /usr/bin folder

Tags: 14.04, permissions, eclipse

Linux newbie here.This might be a little redundant but I didn't get a satisfying answer, so posting it again. The issue is with permissions in the `/usr/bin` folder.

I need to install eclipse, and one of the steps mentions creating a eclipe.desktiop file in `/usr/bin/applications` directory.

Here is the guide which I followed :

http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/

So I am running this command to create this file

```
gedit eclipse.desktop
```

in the `/usr/bin/applications`

But when I try saving it, it says that I don't have the required permissions.

I tried reading about this but not finding a satisfying answer- some said to use 777 permission but that is dangerous and I don't want to risk it. So what should I do? 
I assume that this may be due to the reason that I don't have root access to that folder (guessing). If that is so, how do I make myself the root user, because this is my personal system and I will be the sole one using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use :

```
sudo gedit eclipse.desktop
```

instead of

```
gedit eclipse.desktop
```

A standard user cannot alter most of the files or directories except those which are in home folder. In your question you want to modify a file located at /usr/bin. Thus super user privilege are required for modifying the file.

Hence using *sudo* before *gedit* solves the problem.

*sudo* means superuser do, i.e. the user can do superuser operations for an interactive shell

Comment: You may upvote for my answer, if it worked. Just click ^

Comment: While that answers the question, you might want to explain permissions or provide a link for further info - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: edited my answer with somewhat explanation

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I an going through the link mentioned here.And also reading about the various other commands.

Comment: @ubuntu99 I don't have the required reputation points to up vote the answer :(